# Joint distribution of independent log normal random variables

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, normal-distribution

There are $N$ sticks of length $l_1, \ldots, l_N$. I ask a robot to measure the length of sticks. Robot's measurements are imprecise: given a true length $l$, robot returns $l + x$, where error $x \sim \mathcal{LogN}(\log{l}, \frac{1}{2})$ is a log-normally distributed random variable. I want to estimate the probability that the sum of errors $x_1 + \ldots + x_N$ (here $x_i$ corresponds to the true length $l_i$) is greater than a constant $\alpha$, i.e.
$$\mathbb{P}(x_1 + \ldots + x_N > \alpha)$$.

(here we use the fact that $x_i \geq 0$ due to log normality.

**Sketch of solution**

Clearly $$\mathbb{P}(x_1 + \ldots + x_N > \alpha) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(x_1 + \ldots + x_N \leq \alpha)$$ (again used the fact that $\sum x_i$ is non-negative)

Since $x_i$ are independent, the joint density of $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is given by
$$p(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \frac{1}{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)^{\frac{N}{2}} x_1 \cdots x_n} \cdot e^{
- \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(\log \dfrac{x_i}{l_i}\right)^2}$$

Thus we shall calculate the integral
$$\int_{x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_N \leq \alpha} p(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \, dx_1 \cdots dx_n$$

Consider a mapping $t_i = \log \frac{x_i}{l_i}$. The Jacobian of the mapping is $J = \operatorname{diag}\left(\dfrac{1}{l_i x_i}\right)$, thus by change of variables formula, we have
$$\int_{x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_N \leq \alpha} p(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \, dx_1 \cdots dx_n = \int_{e^{t_1 l_i} + \ldots + e^{t_N l_N} \leq \alpha} l_1 \ldots l_N \cdot \left( \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)^{-\dfrac{N}{2}} \cdot e^{- \sum_i t_i^2} \, dt_1 \cdots dt_n$$.

Just I don't see easy ways to proceed further (given the unusual form of constraint). Is there any hint? Are there any ways to approach the problem (maybe not by straightforward computation)?

Comment: perhaps turn the constraint into a $\delta$, then work in Fourier space and do a saddle point approximation?

Comment: Sums of more than, say, $3$ or $4$ lognormals are hard to deal with if you want an exact closed form solution. When $n$ is large, Monte Carlo simulation is the easiest and least error prone way to go.

Comment: @KurtG. Exactly. As I understood, there are some known approximation schemes that do not require Monte-Carlo sampling (like approximation the sum $\sum_i X_i$ of log-normal r.v. with a log-normal), which are not as accurate as sampling-based methods, but provide a reasonable approximation.

Comment: The simplest way to approximate a sum of independent lognormals by a lognormal is to match the expectation and the variance of the final lognormal which you want to be the approximation. Since the lognormal has no more degrees of freedom than expectation and variance that's as good as it gets. Try it and compare with Monte Carlo.  I agree with Doron Zeilberger that mathematics is an experimental science.